# Not able to read text using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to read the text from h2 tag but my script is failing to read it and comes up as blank. However when i try to read the p tag, it reads it correctly.Can some  one pls. advice?
Below is the HTML:

```
<div class="phys-search-block">
<div class="phys-item">
    <img class="left phys-photo" width="80" border="0" alt="Placehold"                  src="http://drphotos.partners.org/photos/BWH_1295769966_20130110.jpg">
    <h2>Adler, Dale S., MD</h2>
    <p>
    Cardiovascular Disease
    <br>
    Internal Medicine
    <br>
    </p>
</div>
```

Below is my C# code:

```
 IList<IWebElement> lst3 =     driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_MainsiteGenericContent_PhysSearchContent")).FindElements(By.ClassName("phys-search-block"));
       bool tst0 = lst3[0].FindElement(By.ClassName("phys- item")).FindElement(By.TagName("h2")).Displayed;
       Console.WriteLine(tst0);
       string adlertest = lst3[0].FindElement(By.ClassName("phys-item")).FindElement(By.TagName("h2")).Text;
       Console.WriteLine(adlertest);
       ITakesScreenshot dr1 = driver as ITakesScreenshot;
       dr1.GetScreenshot().SaveAsFile("C:\\Adler1.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: 2nd line of code: `By.ClassName("phys- item")` has an extra space in the class name. Also, case sensitivity might be an issue, try using `H2`.

Comment: Can I suggest you use reasonable names for your variables? `dr1`...? Why not simply `screenshotDriver`? `tst0`? What's that about? Why not `isDiplayed`? Give things semantic meaning.